# Raw JSON for Key:Value

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, testing

I have been looking for ages and found some similar questions but no answers which fixed my issue.

I have recently developed a Web API project with seperate server side and client side code. I am wanting to do some testing through apiary, mainly for posting data. This requires me to have a "sample" of the posted JSON. However i cannot seem to get a working sample (I am using Postman to test the JSON).

I am sending a ViewModel:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
    {
        public ExampleModel exampleModel { get; set; }
        public String[] strings { get; set; }
    }
```

With the model:

```
public class ExampleModel 
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Recieved { get; set; }
        public bool CompleteRemotly { get; set; }
        public bool CompleteInField { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> RecievedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> ScheduledFor { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> CompleteOn { get; set; }
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        public string DiagnosticReports { get; set; }
        public string CReference { get; set; }
        public string JReference { get; set; }
    }
```

The format the POST is expecting is:

```
Key: "evm", 
Value: {APIProject.ViewModels.ExampleViewModel}
```

And:

```
APIProject.ViewModels.ExampleViewModel:
{
   strings = [""],
   exampleModel = {ExampleModel}
}
```

My latest attempt is:

```
{
    "evm":{
        "ExampleViewModel":{
            "exampleModel":{
                "ID":0,
                "User":"Harrison",
                "Title":"Other",
                "Type":"Other",
                "Description":"ygfvgufuf",
                "Recieved":true,
                "CompleteRemotly":false,
                "CompleteInField":false,
                "Email":null,
                "RecievedDate":"\/Date(1458133155546)\/",
                "ScheduledFor":null,
                "CompleteOn":null,
                "Priority":"Low",
                "DiagnosticReports":null,
                "CPA_Reference":null,
                "Jira_Reference":null,
                "strings":[]
            },
            "strings":[""]
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns:

```
Key: "evm", 
Value: {APIProject.ViewModels.ExampleViewModel}
```

And:

```
APIProject.ViewModels.ExampleViewModel:
{
   strings = null,
   exampleModel = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i got this to work by sending the following JSON, I guess i was over complicating the situation.

```
{
   "requestManagements":{
                "RequestID":0,
                "User":"Harrison",
                "RequestTitle":"Other",
                "RequestType":"Other",
                "RequestDescription":"ygfvgufuf",
                "RequestRecieved":true,
                "RequestCompleteRemotly":false,
                "RequestCompleteInField":false,
                "Email":null,
                "RequestRecievedDate":"\/Date(1458133155546)\/",
                "ScheduledFor":null,
                "CompleteOn":null,
                "Priority":"Low",
                "DiagnosticReports":null,
                "CPA_Reference":null,
                "Jira_Reference":null,
                "RequestManagerImages":[]
            },
    "images":[""]
}
```